# Make an vertical array horizontal in js (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

I want to make a vertical array to be a vertical array in discord.js
This is supposed to send the text in regional letters horizontally, but it send vertically. I checked on stackoverflow, but i found nothing about what i wanted to do , so if you could help me out, this should be nice.

Here is my code:

```
var Letters = {
    a:":regional_indicator_a:", 
    b:":regional_indicator_b:", 
    c:":regional_indicator_c:",
    d:":regional_indicator_d:",
    e:":regional_indicator_e:",
    f:":regional_indicator_f:",
    g:":regional_indicator_g:",
    h:":regional_indicator_h:",
    i:":regional_indicator_i:",
    j:":regional_indicator_j:",
    k:":regional_indicator_k:",
    l:":regional_indicator_l:",
    m:":regional_indicator_m:",
    n:":regional_indicator_n:",
    o:":regional_indicator_o:",
    p:":regional_indicator_p:",
    q:":regional_indicator_q:",
    r:":regional_indicator_r:",
    s:":regional_indicator_s:",
    t:":regional_indicator_t:",
    u:":regional_indicator_u:",
    v:":regional_indicator_v:",
    w:":regional_indicator_w:",
    x:":regional_indicator_x:",
    y:":regional_indicator_y:",
    z:":regional_indicator_z:"
};

let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
let data = args.slice(0).join(" ");
var chars = data.split('');
function getRegional(letter){
    if(letter === "a" || letter === "A"){ return Letters.a; } 
    if(letter === "b" || letter === "B"){ return Letters.b; }
    if(letter === "c" || letter === "C"){ return Letters.c; }
    if(letter === "d" || letter === "D"){ return Letters.d; }
    if(letter === "e" || letter === "E"){ return Letters.e; }
    if(letter === "f" || letter === "F"){ return Letters.f; }
    if(letter === "g" || letter === "G"){ return Letters.g; }
    if(letter === "h" || letter === "H"){ return Letters.h; }
    if(letter === "i" || letter === "I"){ return Letters.i; }
    if(letter === "j" || letter === "J"){ return Letters.j; }
    if(letter === "k" || letter === "K"){ return Letters.k; }
    if(letter === "l" || letter === "L"){ return Letters.l; }
    if(letter === "m" || letter === "M"){ return Letters.m; }
    if(letter === "n" || letter === "N"){ return Letters.n; }
    if(letter === "o" || letter === "O"){ return Letters.o; }
    if(letter === "p" || letter === "P"){ return Letters.p; }
    if(letter === "q" || letter === "Q"){ return Letters.q; }
    if(letter === "r" || letter === "R"){ return Letters.r; }
    if(letter === "s" || letter === "S"){ return Letters.s; }
    if(letter === "t" || letter === "T"){ return Letters.t; }
    if(letter === "u" || letter === "U"){ return Letters.u; }
    if(letter === "v" || letter === "V"){ return Letters.v; }
    if(letter === "w" || letter === "W"){ return Letters.w; }
    if(letter === "x" || letter === "X"){ return Letters.x; }
    if(letter === "y" || letter === "Y"){ return Letters.y; }
    if(letter === "z" || letter === "Z"){ return Letters.z; }
    if(letter === " "){ return ' '; }
}

var LettersToSend = [];

chars.forEach(element => {
    console.log('Lettre: ' + element)
    console.log('Regional letter: ' + getRegional(element))
    LettersToSend.push(getRegional(element));  
});
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I hope that you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You do realize that you can drastically shorten your code using `return Letters[letter]` instead of those useless if statements?

Comment: What do you end up doing with the `LettersToSend` array? There may be some generic discord library print emoji function that defaults to `endlines` between items for an array, which you may be able to overwrite to a space instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an optimised version of your code that should give you the correct results.

Any characters that aren't letters are replaced with a space.

```js
let args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
let data = args.slice(0).join(' ');
let chars = data.split('');

function getRegional(letter) {
    return (!/^[a-zA-Z]$/g.test(letter))? '          ' :
        `:regional_indicator_${ letter.toLowerCase() }:`;
}

let lettersToSend = [];
lettersToSend = chars.map(element => {
    console.log('Letter: ' + element);
    console.log('Regional letter: ' + getRegional(element));
    return getRegional(element);  
});

message.channel.send(lettersToSend.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

this code should work for you.

```js
function exec(message) {
    var hash = {
        a: ":regional_indicator_a:",
        b: ":regional_indicator_b:",
        c: ":regional_indicator_c:",
        d: ":regional_indicator_d:",
        e: ":regional_indicator_e:",
        f: ":regional_indicator_f:",
        g: ":regional_indicator_g:",
        h: ":regional_indicator_h:",
        i: ":regional_indicator_i:",
        j: ":regional_indicator_j:",
        k: ":regional_indicator_k:",
        l: ":regional_indicator_l:",
        m: ":regional_indicator_m:",
        n: ":regional_indicator_n:",
        o: ":regional_indicator_o:",
        p: ":regional_indicator_p:",
        q: ":regional_indicator_q:",
        r: ":regional_indicator_r:",
        s: ":regional_indicator_s:",
        t: ":regional_indicator_t:",
        u: ":regional_indicator_u:",
        v: ":regional_indicator_v:",
        w: ":regional_indicator_w:",
        x: ":regional_indicator_x:",
        y: ":regional_indicator_y:",
        z: ":regional_indicator_z:"
    };


    var msg = "";
    var letters = args.join(" ");


    function getRegional(letter) {
        return (letter === " " ? " " : hash[letter])
    }

    for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        msg += getRegional(letters[i])
    }

    console.log(msg)
}

let msg = {
    content: '!regional two three'
}

let [command, ...args] = msg.content.slice(1).split(/\s+/g)

exec(args)
```

running this code returned this for me (im assuming this is what you want)

```
:regional_indicator_t::regional_indicator_w::regional_indicator_o: :regional_indicator_t::regional_indicator_h::regional_indicator_r::regional_indicator_e::regional_indicator_e:
```

Comment: just put a .toLowerCase() after the args.join(" ")

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of doing that many `if` you can just check for the property.
`variable.property` could also be written as `variable['propery']` with the difference you can add variables. so in the `getRegional(letter)` you can check for a property you passed down. `if(!Letters[letter]) return ' ';`. Then `return` the property.

```js
var Letters = {
    a: ":regional_indicator_a:",
    b: ":regional_indicator_b:",
    c: ":regional_indicator_c:",
    d: ":regional_indicator_d:",
    e: ":regional_indicator_e:",
    f: ":regional_indicator_f:",
    g: ":regional_indicator_g:",
    h: ":regional_indicator_h:",
    i: ":regional_indicator_i:",
    j: ":regional_indicator_j:",
    k: ":regional_indicator_k:",
    l: ":regional_indicator_l:",
    m: ":regional_indicator_m:",
    n: ":regional_indicator_n:",
    o: ":regional_indicator_o:",
    p: ":regional_indicator_p:",
    q: ":regional_indicator_q:",
    r: ":regional_indicator_r:",
    s: ":regional_indicator_s:",
    t: ":regional_indicator_t:",
    u: ":regional_indicator_u:",
    v: ":regional_indicator_v:",
    w: ":regional_indicator_w:",
    x: ":regional_indicator_x:",
    y: ":regional_indicator_y:",
    z: ":regional_indicator_z:"
};

let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
let data = args.slice(0).join(" ");
var chars = data.split('');

function getRegional(letter) {
    if(!Letters[letter.toLowerCase()]) return ' '; // If property doesn't exist return ''
    return Letters[letter.toLowerCase()];          // If it does, return it.
}

var LettersToSend = [];

chars.forEach(element => {
    console.log('Lettre: ' + element)
    console.log('Regional letter: ' + getRegional(element))
    LettersToSend.push(getRegional(element));
});
message.channel.send(LettersToSend.join('')); // Send it in a single String.
```

Hope this code helps and makes it Easier.